# submit Ajax form in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have a form which has some fields .I want to show some labels when the user enter number in a textbox in one of the form fields.
I know that I have to use Ajax but the problem is the Ajax form is in another form. So when I submit Ajax form the outter form is submit and I can not get Ajax request.
Here is my code structure:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset style="font-family:'B Nazanin';font-size:14pt">
    <div align="center">        
        <table border="0">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.a)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.a)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.a)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.a)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div align="right" id="searchJustForm">
         <fieldset style="font-family:'B Nazanin';font-size:14pt">                             
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Terminal", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divGomrokJust", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
            {
            <div align="center">
```

thank you for you attention.

Comment: Nested `form` elements in HTML are illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest HTML forms. That's invalid HTML. You will have to modify your markup. You could use pure jQuery by subscribing for `.change` events of your form elements and trigger an AJAX request using the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Using $.post Javascript function from jQuery library (www.jquery.com) would be the best solution